# Not able to add collections to facebook app using new admin interface

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Facebook Opengraph has a feature called collections.

The admin pages for apps on facebook recently changed, and now I can't find where to add collections for my app. I've searched online for a few hours, and apparently the management page used to be at `https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/APP_ID/open-graph/collections`, but that page is now blank for me, and /x/apps/APP_ID/open-graph only shows me stories, actions types and object types. How can I manage my app's collections? What do I need to do?

Here's a [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/qROHFq8iX) of the new admin interface, and what it looks like for me (i.e. no collections).

Thanks, 
John

Comment: What browser you are currently using?. Because it's not looking like normal browser.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, the screenshot I took is not the full window, it's just a partial clip to show the problem. I was using Chrome at the time and have tried on other browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

In page of your app, there will be an option named `Collections`. Please see the screenshot below. I am using Firefox browser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks sathiamoorthy, but unfortunately your screenshot shows that you are using the old admin interface. The issue only arises with the new interface, as far as I can tell. Thanks.